# Why it is giving me code:400 and connection close?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

Response:

> Optional({ URL: myurllink } { status code: 400, headers {     Connection = close;     "Content-Language" = en;     "Content-Length" = 1105;     "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf-8";

Code below:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.myurl/")!)
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

var params1 = ["dailyspecial_name" : dailyspecial_name.text!,
              "dailyspecial_description" : dailyspecial_description.text!,
              "dailyspecial_type" :dailyspecial_type.text!]

var params = ["data" : params1,"label" : ""] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
var err: NSError?
request.HTTPBody = (try!NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options:  NSJSONWritingOptions()))
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    print("Response: \(response)")
    var strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("Body: \(strData)")
    var err: NSError?
    var json = (try!NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)) as? NSDictionary

    // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
    if(err != nil) {
        print(err!.localizedDescription)
        let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
    }
    else {
        // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
        // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
        if let parseJSON = json {
            // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
            var success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
            print("Succes: \(success)")
        }
        else {
            // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
        }
    }
})

task.resume()
```

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. Please update your question and add your code as actual text by copying and pasting the actual code. Be sure you format it correctly. This makes it much easier to read and reference when providing answers.

Comment: Edit the code. Could you please review the code. Thanks

Comment: A 400 means you sent bad JSON data most of the time.  You'll have to look at the specification of the URL you are posting to in order to see exactly what it wants.